# PYTHON- Merging CSV file based on same value in colunm 1

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have 2 CSV files, both with thousands of lines each, which I would like to merge and output to a new file (results.csv). 
I have looked here at other answers but now need assistance.

Please note:
-Neither file have headers 
- I do NOT want to use PANDA

File 1 (file.csv) contains:

> 041, 2017111, 50501342, 20058987, 200765893, PPP, PLUS, D, NSW
>
> 455, 2017082, 50513457, 20068678, 200476768, BBB, LONG, A, NSW
>
> 178, 2017976, 50586956, 20089765, 200886565, LLL, PLUS, D, QLD

File 2 (file2.csv) contains:

> 019, 0.000, 20150907, 20170308
>
> 041, 0.000, 20160806, 20170504
>
> 455, 147.533, 20140402, 20170506

Expected (results.csv) output:

> 041, 2017111, 50501342, 20058987, 200765893, PPP, PLUS, D, NSW, 0.000, 20160806, 20170504
>
> 455, 2017082, 50513457, 20068678, 200476768, BBB, LONG, A, NSW, 147.533, 20140402, 20170506

So the code will sort through and join when column 1 is the same.

So far I have tried the below but the output is in the wrong format:

```
f1 = open(file.csv', 'r')
f2 = open(file2.csv', 'r')
f3 = open('results.csv', 'w')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

file2 = list(c2)

for file1_row in c1:
    row = 1
    found = False
    results_row = file1_row  
    for file2_row in file2:        
        x = file2_row[1:]
        if file1_row[0] == file2_row[0]:
            results_row.append(x)
            found = True
            break
    row += 1
    if not found:
        results_row.append('Not found')     
    c3.writerow(results_row)



f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you don't need to use in `pandas`, [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) included in python. You can create in memory db with python and sqlite and perform a join.

Comment: @sKwa I am unfamiliar with this so not very helpful- sorry

Comment: its a fundamental problem of data base(linear algebra), without any special storage optimization(data structure) a brute force is the only way to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
import csv
f1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv'))
f2 = csv.reader(open('file2.csv'))
final_file = csv.writer(open('file_output.csv', 'a'))
final_file.writerows([a+b for a, b in zip(f1, f2)])
```

Comment: I seem to have a MemoryError with this- Is there a more efficient way?